# MDX - Sum one measure at leaf lvl where another measure exists at leaf lvl

Tags: mdx

I need to work out Stockturn at any lvl in an item hierarchy.

So far the calc is SUM the last 3 months [COGS] * 4 divided by [SOH] (SOH Value)

The below is embedded in a BI tool and works. It is in the Item grid and filters for every member in the Item dimension at the level display:
((SUM({.lag(3):.lag(1)}, ([Type].[Type].[Actual], [Measures].[Cogs]))) * 4) /
([Type].[Type].[Actual], [Measures].[SOH], )

What it needs changed/added is only returning [SOH] for Items where the [COGS] measure has values.
So if I have items that do not have COGS then do not include them:

| Item | SOH | COGS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 20 |
| B | 15 | 40 |
| C | 20 |  |

Do not include C as it will throw the calc.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach - assuming you are using SSAS 2012 or newer - would be to use `Divide` instead of the division operator `/`:

```
Divide( ((SUM({.lag(3):.lag(1)}, ([Type].[Type].[Actual], [Measures].[Cogs]))) * 4),
        ([Type].[Type].[Actual], [Measures].[SOH], )
      )
```

[Divide](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/mdx/divide-mdx) returns `NULL` (empty value) instead of infinity when dividing by zero or null.

**Edit**: I see you want to avoid the calculation of the numerator is null or 0, not the denominator. In this case, you would use `Iif`:

```
IIF((SUM({.lag(3):.lag(1)}, ([Type].[Type].[Actual], [Measures].[Cogs])) <> 0,
    ((SUM({.lag(3):.lag(1)}, ([Type].[Type].[Actual], [Measures].[Cogs]))) * 4)
    /
    ([Type].[Type].[Actual], [Measures].[SOH], )
   , NULL)
```

[`Iif`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/mdx/iif-mdx) is a function with three arguments, a condition, the value to use if the condition is true, and the condition to use if the condition is false.